# Proper entitlements to automatically open directory on macOS

Tags: electron, electron-builder, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

I build an app with electron that saves text to files in a user selected directory. On app startup the user selects the directory where his data should be stored. I save that directory with `electron-settings` and with the next app startup the directory is automatically loaded again.

Locally everything works great, but I have trouble getting it to work packaged for an macOS .app file and after signing.

My entitlements currently look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <string>APPLE_GROUP_STRING</string>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.document-scope</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

When I select a directory everything works great, but when I close the app and then try to read/write files to the same directory I get a 'permission denied' error. (After manually selecting the directory again it works as expected)

What entitlement do I need to set to allow accessing the directory on startup?
Is there another workaround? Maybe have one button that directly opens the directory without the usual file-selection dialog?

I already tried to use

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write</key>
<array>
    <string>/</string>
</array>
```

but for very obvious reason apple verification rejected the app with read/write access to `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks @mahal tertin for pointing to the right direction with security scoped bookmarks.

since electron 6.0.0 the `dialog.showOpenDialog()` method returns a promise that resolves to the filePaths and security scoped bookmarks.

with the `app.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource(bookmark)` you can now use that bookmark to access the previous resource.

I wrote a detailed blog post with code examples for more information: https://developapa.com/security-scoped-bookmark/

Answer (score 1):

Try to save the directory not only with `electron-settings` but also as [Security Scoped Bookmark](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16). You then can access this directory again after restart.

Comment: thanks for your answer. just this day stumbled upon the security scoped bookmarks and their usage in electron
https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appstartaccessingsecurityscopedresourcebookmarkdata-macos-mas

will write detailed answer once fully implemented